# Bootstrap 3 dropdowns not working via javascript click action

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a large dropdown help menu that I'd like to open normally from the menu AND also open from a link outside of the dropdown menu structure.

JS Fiddle of broken scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/tmfzog1j/1/

When I run `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown("toggle");` from the browser console, it works fine, which makes me think it's some kind of event.propagation problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## works

you have to stop propagation on that puppy, so you were totally right.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.remote').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle');
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/osch5w2w/)